# import configuration file when batch start ? (OS=Windows)

Tags: windows, unix, command-line-interface, batch-file, import

I write batch file and it has a large number of variable so i decided to put all variable on text file (`conf.txt`) and import it at the beginning of batch file so please i need the command line do this task (import the `conf.txt` to the batch file)

and in the next step i want to write bash file on unix and do the same proccess so please if you can explain method to the both operating system windows and unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763875/dos-batch-file-include-external-file-for-variables

Bash

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192292/bash-how-best-to-include-other-scripts